# What is the point of printf's length modifier flags?

Tags: c++, printf

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) has a series of "length modifier" flags you can pass in the format specifications, for example `%d` is for an `int` argument, but `%hhd` is for a `signed char` (8-bit) and `%lld` is a `long long` (64-bit).

I can see why this is necessary for larger-than-`int` types, but smaller types are [implicitly promoted to `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) anyway.

In what situation would `%hhd` give a different output to `%d`, assuming you actually do pass a `signed char`?

Comment: I imagine it's to maintain symmetry with `scanf`. Possibly to allow the same format string for both.

Answer (score 5):

The promotion will preserve the signedness. The compiler knows the type of the variable, but the `printf` does not. If you try to print a signed variable with an unsigned conversation specifier, it'll treat the variable differently (i.e, printing out sign-extended F's). The length modifier `hh` says you explicitly want to print the signed char with an unsigned format. Live example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char* s = "\u00d1"; /* Ñ */
  for (char* p = s; *p; ++p) printf("%02X (%02hhX)\n", *p, *p);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
FFFFFFC3 (C3)
FFFFFF91 (91)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the length modifiers for reading shorter data with `scanf`. Because `printf` and `scanf` shares the mostly same set of formatting strings, including modifiers, it's retained primarily of consistence concerns.